# set selected value select2 from database with icon flags

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-select2

i'm doing edit profile page i've problem with select2 for country. i'm using html and php. below is my code for jquery.

```
function formatCountry (country) {

            if (!country.id) { return country.text; }
            var $country = $(
                '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-'+ country.id.toLowerCase() +' flag-icon-squared"></span>' +
                '<span class="flag-text">'+ country.text+"</span>"
            );
            return $country;
        };


        $("[name='country']").select2({
            placeholder: "Select a country",
            templateResult: formatCountry,
            data: isoCountries

        });
        $("#country").val('<?php echo  $profile_fields[11]["value"];?>').trigger('change');
```

My code only display country name.how to add icon flag? [output my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXgCA.png)

Comment: `templateResult: formatCountry` is for the dropdown. `templateSelection: formatCountry` would use the same function for the selected value as well I believe.

Comment: oh yes it works! Thank you @apokryfos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i add **templateSelection**

`$("[name='country']").select2({
                placeholder: "Select a country",
                templateResult: formatCountry,
                templateSelection: formatCountry,
                data: isoCountries,
                id: '<?php echo  $profile_fields[11]["value"];?>'
            });`